# Detecting wrong request url in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-deployment

I have deployed a c# web application on server. And in global.asax file i have printed the request url . But it is showing wrong. And displaying request url twice like (http://test.com/test.com/). 
But on local it is working fine. I am unable to find the problem. 
Code used to print the url

```
  void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      string requesturl = Request.Url.ToString();
      Response.Write("<br/>requesturl  " + requesturl);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which event in your global.asax are you printing this message?

Answer (score 0):

Use this **System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)**.It will return only the left part of your host.If this didnt work,Show me what is the value of **relative url** and also **global.asax** code.